# Using multiple @GenericGenerator?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I experimented with Hibernate's `@GenericGenerator` in a Spring Boot project (Hibernate 5). Made a test entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class BatchTest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3012542467060581674L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "batchTestIdGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "batchTestIdGenerator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size",value = "1000")
            }
    )
    private long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String someVal;
...
```

Using this generator I can insert entities really fast with JPA (I have a Spring Repository, served by a `@Service`) and it's cool, but how is the sequence actually stored? My database currently is an SQL Server 2016 instance, and in the schema, I can see that I have a `dbo.hibernate_sequence`:
[image]

If I create a second entity, with a different generator, I get an exception during startup:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "batchTestIdGenerator2", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "batchTestIdGenerator2",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size",value = "500")
        }
)
private long id;

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Multiple references to database sequence [hibernate_sequence] were encountered attempting toset conflicting values for 'increment size'.  Found [500] and [1000]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
```

Can I define different sequences at all? It seems like It tries to use the same `dbo.hibernate_sequence` for both sequences (id did not create a new dbo sequence in the database) and just disregards the name. If it is possible to define `N` number of sequence, how can I do it?

Edit: I tried to create the sequences manually (matching names), but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate allow you to create your own Sequence generator, that allows you to define the  format , table everything using Hibernate `IdentifierGenerator`.
Please try below approach.

Create a `SequenceGenerator` class by implementing `IdentifierGenerator`, Use `org.hibernate.id.Configurable` interface to make your Generator configurable -*that will accept parameters from the Entity class*-

Custom identifier generator looks like this:

```
public class StringSequenceIdentifier 
        implements IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

    public static final String SEQUENCE_PREFIX = "sequence_prefix";

    private String sequencePrefix;

    private String sequenceCallSyntax;

    @Override
    public void configure(
            Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
            throws MappingException {
        final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment =
                serviceRegistry.getService(JdbcEnvironment.class);
        final Dialect dialect = jdbcEnvironment.getDialect();

        sequencePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(
                SEQUENCE_PREFIX,
                params,
                "SEQ_");

        final String sequencePerEntitySuffix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(
                SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY_SUFFIX,
                params,
                SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_SUFFIX);

        final String defaultSequenceName = ConfigurationHelper.getBoolean(
                SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY,
                params,
                false)
                ? params.getProperty(JPA_ENTITY_NAME) + sequencePerEntitySuffix
                : SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_NAME;

        sequenceCallSyntax = dialect.getSequenceNextValString(
                ConfigurationHelper.getString(
                        SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM,
                        params,
                        defaultSequenceName));
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Identifiable) {
            Identifiable identifiable = (Identifiable) obj;
            Serializable id = identifiable.getId();
            if (id != null) {
                return id;
            }
        }
        long seqValue = ((Number) Session.class.cast(session)
            .createSQLQuery(sequenceCallSyntax)
            .uniqueResult()).longValue();

        return sequencePrefix + String.format("%011d%s", 0 ,seqValue);
    }
}
```

Entity Will be like

```
@Entity(name = "Post") @Table(name = "post")
public class Post implements Identifiable<String> {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "assigned-sequence",
        strategy = "com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.identifier.StringSequenceIdentifier",
        parameters = {
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                name = "sequence_name", value = "hibernate_sequence"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                name = "sequence_prefix", value = "CTC_"),
        }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        generator = "assigned-sequence", 
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private String id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Please refer the Below link for detailed explanation.
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-string-based-sequence-identifier-generator-with-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

According to section 11.1.48 SequenceGenerator Annotation of the [JPA 2.1 specification](https://www.google.co.th/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0g_L5zr3XAhVLuY8KHfWpBE0QFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fotn-pub%2Fjcp%2Fpersistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec%2FJavaPersistence.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3YYYXoHlqYYe31KBFa0lRV):

The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit (across all generator types).

So you can't have duplicate generators.

Comment: What is the point of defining the generator with the Entity, if all I can do is copying the same definition to all of them?

Comment: Check the documentation here for 5.0 : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id-generator

Hibernate also provides GenericGenerator which can be used to configure Hibernate specific generator by passing in strategy attribute. However you can define a custom generator use GenericGenerator annotation